# Add custom button to navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

So I want to add a custom settings button with a custom background image in my navigation controller. Currently I tried doing this:

```swift
        func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            /// Settings button:
            let settingsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
            settingsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Configuration Icon"), for: .normal)
            settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(configurationTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: settingsButton)
        }
```

When I tap this button, `configurationTapped` gets triggered, but the problem is that the button doesn't blink as it normally does when I put it outside the navigation controller..

How can I solve this?? 
Should I create a custom animation every time the action gets called, or am I missing something here?

Comment: i tried your block of code on a sample project and the button "blinks"(if by blink you mean, the image is tinted black) for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let yourButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: yourImage, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(yourSelector))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourButton
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use `.done` because Apple doc says: _"The style for a done button—for example, a button that completes some task and returns to the previous view."_. And I thought that it would dismiss my current ViewController. @AbhiRaz

Answer (score 0):

You can use property to a button:

```
settingsButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
```

Apple Doc says, "*A Boolean value that determines whether tapping the button causes it to glow.*"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that made my button blink, but it did it in a strange way. It just blinked at the center, not the whole button.